# Ember's template rendering pipeline

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a specific template for both the main app and the public facing pages.  Based on the docs the code below is what I thought should work.  However I continually get a `Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined` error thrown.

#### router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('app');
  this.route('login');
});
```

#### application.hbs

```
{{outlet}}
```

#### public.hbs

```
This is the public template
{{outlet}}
```

#### app.hbs

```
This is the app template
{{outlet}}
```

#### login.hbs

```
<input type="email" ...>
<input type="password" ...>
```

#### routes/login.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('login', { into: 'public' });
  }
});
```

#### routes/app.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('login', { into: 'public' });
  }
});
```

If I remove the {into:..} options no error is thrown but both the login and app templates are rendered into the application template rather then the public and app respectively.

Am I totally misunderstanding how Ember handles the rendering?

Answer (score 0):

In the app that I'm doing with ember I also use the renderTemplate hook to render a template into another one, your code there is the same as mine and looks good.

I think the problem might be that there isn't any public route. I think that if you define one in your router, and then try again, it may work. Looks to me like its not able to render the templates into public because public does not exist.